# Execute load test with 0.1 million concurrent threads via JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, master-slave

I'm a newbie to JMeter and I'm told to perform load test with 0.1 million concurrent threads via JMeter. Will each Server configuration of 16GB RAM,4 VCPU's be sufficient in master/slave configuration to handle the load.

I tried with 1000 users initially on a machine with configuration of 4GB RAM and 2VCPU's but it resulted in OOM Error.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know because each load test is different and has different requirements in terms of underlying OS resources.

You need to measure this yourself.

1. Install JMeter on that server
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Make sure to setup monitoring of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. usage, you can either make use of your operating system monitoring mechanisms or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
4. Start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until any of monitored metrics usage exceeds, say, 80% of total available capacity
5. At this stage check how many users were active using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)

This is how many users you can simulate from particularly this machine for particularly this test. If you change the machine or change the test - you will need to re-run the exercise.

If the amount is 100 000 or more - you're all set, if not - divide 100 000 by the number of users you were able to reach, add 1 to this and you will know how many machines of the given hardware specifications you will need to conduct your rest in [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) mode.